# F# - Using Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove with dotnet 5

Tags: .net, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm migrating my F# code from dotnet3.1 to 5 and struggling with following code:

```
        let tryRemove key (dict: Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'a, 'b>) =
           match dict.TryRemove(key) with
           | (true, v) -> Some v
           | (false, _) -> None
```

In 3.1 `TryRemove` returned tuple, in version 5 it returnes only boolean value. To get value from dictionary I need to pass reference as second parameter of `TryRemove`.
What is the correct way to do it and avoid returning null v?

I have tried following code:

```
    let tryRemove key (dict: Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'a, 'b>): 'b option =
       let mutable v: 'b = null
       match dict.TryRemove(key, &v) with
       | true -> Some v
       | _ -> None
```

But now function that uses it thinks that it is possible to have null inside that Option from `tryRemove`

> error FS0001: The type '(Body -> unit)' does not have 'null' as a proper value

where `b' is (Body -> unit)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that .NET 5 added an overload. Before there was only `TryRemove (key : 'a, byref<'b> value) : bool`, now the new overload `TryRemove(item: KeyValuePair<'a, 'b>) : bool` gets chosen. See [netcore 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove?view=netcore-3.1) vs [NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove?view=net-5.0)

An alternative solution is to add a type annotation, e.g.

```
let tryRemove (key: 'a) (dict: Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'a, 'b>) =
   match dict.TryRemove(key) with
   | (true, v) -> Some v
   | (false, _) -> None
```

Answer (score 4):

I have just figured out the:

```
let mutable v = Unchecked.defaultof<'b>
```

instead of

```
let mutable v: 'b = null
```

works, but it's super strange the <strike>simplified syntax with *last out argument* translated to *tuple result* does not work anymore</strike>. Does it?

EDIT
It still works! See the right answer :)